# Access <body> from React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm new to React and I am trying to build a standalone Header component containing a 'slide in sidebar'. I used state to apply CSS to slide the sidebar in/out:

```
constructor() {
super();
  this.state = {
    sideBar: false
  }
}
handleSidebar() {
  this.setState({
    sideBar: !this.state.sideBar
  });
}
render() {
return(
  <header>
   <ul style={this.state.sideBar ? {'transform': 'translateX(0%)'} : null}></ul>
   <button onClick={this.handleSidebar.bind(this)}></button>
  </header>
)
```

This does the job in terms of sliding the sidebar, but once the sidebar is open, I would like to lock scroll on body by applying `overflow:hidden` to the `<body>`. However since `<body>` is outside of React, I was wondering how it's possible to access the tag?

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/hollow3d/pen/OjKByb)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `document.body` to set the styles you need. Make sure you access `document` after it's ready, so put the code in `componentWillMount`. You should reset the styles after unmounting the component in `componentWillUnmount`.

```
componentWillMount() {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.style.overflow = "visible"; // or restore the original value
}
```

---

After your comment I realized that you need to set the styles after opening the sidebar. Here some notes:

1. Don't use `this.state` in `setState`. `setState` is asynchronous, therefore you should use the optional `prevState` parameter to access the previous state object.
2. You could use the optional second parameter of `setState` which is a function and is called after the state is updated. In this function you could set the styles of the body.
3. You can `bind` the function in the constructor.
4. In the constructor pass the `props` to the base constructor (`super(props)`).
5. Rename `sideBar` to `isSideBarOpen`. It is a more descriptive name.

Here is the final code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isSideBarOpen: false
    };
    this.toggleSideBar.bind(this);
}

updateBodyStyles() {
    if (this.state.isSideBarOpen) {
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    } else {
        document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
    }
}

toggleSideBar() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return { isSideBarOpen: !prevState.isSideBarOpen }
    }, this.updateBodyStyles);
}

render() {
    return (
       <header>
            <ul style={this.state.isSideBarOpen? {'transform': 'translateX(0%)'} : null}></ul>
            <button onClick={this.toggleSideBar}></button>
       </header>
    )
```

Comment: Hey thanks Dávid, I tried adding the styles to body once the component WillMount, but since the <Header> component is always present in my app, it just locks the scroll on body. Does it mean I should change the structure of the App? Perhaps adding the sidebar as an another component outside of the <Header>?

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer! I was getting an error that updateBodyStyles is not defined, so I changed it to `this.updateBodyStyles`.

Comment: Happy to help! Thanks for the note, I fixed the answer.

Comment: `document.body.style.overflow` have no effect on the actual value when checking it in dev tools.. Not sure if its some weird logic in my specific project or not

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be inserting a overlay with the sidebar too.

This quick example is just to give you an idea. you can style it as you wish.

```
// style
.navOwerflow {
   display: none;
}
.navOwerflow.open {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 1000px; // get this height from window
   z-index: 2;
   opacity: 0.9;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

 // component
 <header className="header">
        <div className={`navOwerflow ${(this.state.open && 'open')}`}></div>
        <div className="navContainer">
           ...
        </div>
 ...
 </header>
```

Comment: Thanks, fair point. I added the overlay & changed the burger menu to 'X' upon click, however I still can't figure out how to lock the scroll on body.