# Should I access document inside React component in order to create event listeners?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener

I know it is not recommended to access DOM Elements inside React Component using `document.getElementBy...` - I'm using `Ref` instead, if needed.

However, I got into a situation where I want to create an event listener (`omousemove` for example) for the document itself.

Is it okay to access `document.onmousemove` inside a component, or is there another "Reactish" approach that is more recommended, similar to `Ref` for elements, that I'm missing here?

Comment: It's ok, just don't forget to remove the event listener as well.

Comment: Considering `document` is not managed by React and your app wil be mounted inside one its elements, there shouldn't be any problem accessing it directly and attaching an event listener to it. If your event handler doesn't use your React stuff, you can even put it in a script tag inside your root html. You might want to take a look at this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142712/access-body-from-react